# Finding list of jobs from Azure Databricks notebook using code

Tags: azure, jobs, azure-databricks

I found the reference in Databricks that by using REST API I can find number of jobs running in my notebook: [Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/1.2/)

Do you have any simple example implementing this?

Comment: jobs on databricks or Spark jobs inside the notebook?

Comment: Jobs on databricks.Thank you for taking time,i got the resolution.Its via REST API

Answer (score 1):

When you say "running in my notebook" , do you mean running in my cluster ? if yes then the below API should help .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#--list